How to use ShellExecuteEx in the Windows registry?
I want to add a context menu entry which will start a program elevated with admin privileges using the runas verb of ShellExecuteEx. I know how to add the context menu entry and registry command, thus making the entry start the program but I don't know how to use ShellExecuteEx to start the program with the runas verb.
I know I can create a shortcut and set "Run as administrator" in the properties but that is not what I want to do, thank you!

Do you want to be prompted for admin creds, or just "run as administrator"? Please show us what you've tried so far. What is your existing command?

@music2myear, just "run as administrator" . What I've tried so far is written in the question.

Is the account you are running the application as or that you are logged in as already elevated? Will UAC allow elevation without a prompt? What is different between dealing with that prompt and using the Run As Administrator flag in your case? Your question does not clearly indicate what all you have tried. We need specific steps, exact details, etc.

You misunderstand me. I find the concept very interesting, but the question lacks detail because there are a few possible avenues, your preferences and intentions which will specify which is the right one, and will allow for that "very simple" answer you require.

@music2myear, the account is an administrator but it seems its running in admin approval mode, applications are NOT started as admin, unless specifically told to run as admin upon which there is no UAC prompt, as it is set to "Never notify". My goal is to have a context menu entry which will start PowerShell as an administrator under the circumstances described.
